# Password resetter [] is not defined laravel

Tags: laravel-5.7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mEwu.png)hello everyone!
i have been trying to make a custom Authentication system.it's multi Authentication . everything set up now i am getting this error. i have been to solve itt for almost two days. couldn't able to do it. is there anyone help me out.i am using laravel 5.7.it's showing "Password resetter [] is not defined" 
i am getting this error when i am trying reset my admin 
password. built in user password reseting is working fine.

i really appreciate your help.
thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUiey.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNN21.png)

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of pictures of your code.

Comment: i have solved the problem! on my Auth.php instead of     'passwords' => [
        
        'admins' => [

            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
i wrote this     'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

        'admins' => [  'users' => [

            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];